# internal exception : SEH trap 80000100 in module 'KERNELBASE.DLL'[00012F82]

Tags: wine

I am using Proteus in Ubuntu 20.04 with wine. Everything is working fine except whenever I try to save or load a file this error shows up 
**Internal Exception : SEH trap 80000100 in module 'KERNELBASE.DLL'[00012F82]**
***0009:err:module:DelayLoadFailureHook failed to delay load comctl32.dll.HIMAGELIST_QueryInterface
wine: Call from 0x7b032f82 to unimplemented function comctl32.dll.HIMAGELIST_QueryInterface, aborting***

[Error message in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znQ0F.png)  [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYrv2.png)

Comment: As this seems to be about using software, rather than developing it, I vote to move to SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

Seems WINE emulator does not implement the needed function. Maybe you should check out [this](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=43188) soulution?